# how do I create tar file keeping directory structure intact and excluding some files based on the last modified date

Tags: linux, find, tar, filemtime

This is a directory structure:

[image]

I want to tar Directory1 with the conditions -

1. It should include only those files that are modified in the last three days.
2. Keep the directory structure intact.

The final **tared** output should be -

[image]

Comment: I noticed that you never accept answers to your questions. Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers and then revisit your questions and accept the answers which were useful to you.

Answer (score 1):

```
find directory1 -type f -mtime -4d | xargs tar -cf your_archive_name
```

`-mtime -4d`: find all files which were modified in less than 4 days

(`-mtime 3d` will find all files which were modified ***exactly*** 72 hours 00 minutes 00 seconds ago – this is probably not what you are asking for)

Please stay out of directory1 and directory2 while running this command.

Add `-z` option – `tar -czf` – if in addition to archiving the files, you also want to compress them.